# while i am trying to run this code i am getting this error

Tags: python-3.x

while i am compiling this code i am getting error

```
def preprocess_text(genuine, clickbait, vocabulary):
genuine = clean(genuine)
clickbait = clean(clickbait)

words = nltk.word_tokenize(genuine) + nltk.word_tokenize(clickbait)
glove_vocabulary = open("G:\clickbait-detector- 
master\data/vocabulary.glove.txt").read().split("\n")
counts = Counter(word for word in words if word in glove_vocabulary)

vocabulary = [PAD, UNK] + [word for word, count in 
counts.most_common(VOCABULARY_SIZE-2)]
genuine = [mark_unknown_words(vocabulary, sentence)  for sentence in 
tqdm.tqdm(genuine.split("\n"), desc="genuine")]
clickbait = [mark_unknown_words(vocabulary, sentence) for sentence in 
tqdm.tqdm(clickbait.split("\n"), desc="clickbait")]

return (vocabulary, "\n".join(genuine), "\n".join(clickbait))

if __name__ == "__main__":
genuine = open("G:\clickbait-detector-master\data/genuine.txt").read()
clickbait = open("G:\clickbait-detector-master\data/clickbait.txt").read()
vocabulary, genuine_preprocessed, clickbait_preprocessed = 
preprocess_text(genuine, clickbait)
open("G:\clickbait-detector-master\data/vocabulary.txt", 
"w").write("\n".join(vocabulary))
open("G:\clickbait-detector-master\data/genuine.preprocessed.txt", 
"w").write("\n".join(genuine))
open("G:\clickbait-detector-master\data/clickbait.preprocessed.txt", 
"w").write("\n".join(clickbait))
```

my error is 
      TypeError: preprocess_text() missing 1 required positional argument: 
      'vocabulary'

Comment: please format you code correctly and strip it down to a  [**minimal**, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call: `preprocess_text(genuine, clickbait)` only has 2 arguments, your definition: `def preprocess_text(genuine, clickbait, vocabulary):`  demands 3